# Pandas: Unable to merge on two date columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-datetime

I have two dataframes that look like:

df1:

```
    Date       Multiplier
0   1995-01-01  5.248256
1   1995-02-01  5.262376
2   1995-03-01  5.255998
3   1995-04-01  5.215762
4   1995-05-01  5.207806
```

df2:

```
    PRICE   Date
0   77500   1995-01-01
1   60000   1995-01-01
2   39250   1995-01-01
3   51250   1995-01-01
4   224950  1995-01-01
```

Both date columns have been made using the `pd.to_datetime()` method, and they both supposedly have `<M8[ns]` data types when using `df1.Date.dtype` and `df2.Date.dtype`. However when trying to merge the dataframes with `pd.merge(df,hpi,how="left",on="Date")` I get the error:
`ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert the `Date` column of `df1` to a `datetime64`

Check `dtypes` first:

```
>>> df1.dtypes
Date           object    # <- Not a datetime
Multiplier    float64
dtype: object

>>> df2.dtypes
PRICE             int64
Date     datetime64[ns]  # <- Right dtype
dtype: object
```

Convert and merge:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

out = pd.merge(df1, df2,how='left',on='Date')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been at this for so long I thought I already tried this haha